# another git fast-forward merge revert question

Tags: git, merge, git-revert, fast-forward

I was on autopilot last night and unwittingly merged a large feature `feature/bigfeature` branch into our `develop` branch and pushed it to the remote `origin/develop`. I wanted develop to be completely intact and unchanged.

This feature branch was in development for some weeks and part of our workflow was continuously merging origin/develop into it. This makes undoing the merge/push difficult (impossible?)

```
iceddante$ git checkout develop
iceddante$ git merge origin/feature/bigfeature
Updating 94c8d1f0..298b93fe
Fast-forward
<< lots of files >>

iceddante$ git push 
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/Kinesso/api-reach-optimization.git
   94c8d1f0..298b93fe  develop -> develop
```

each branch has several commits over time and it is not clear looking at the history how to untangle this. I tried doing a merge commit revert:

`git revert  94c8d1f0 -m 1`
But this is only reverting the narrow range of commits after the last merge of origin/develop into the feature branch. I identified the merge in the reflog:

```
19f1ac1b (origin/feature/MPL-5178, feature/MPL-5178) HEAD@{16}: checkout: moving from develop to feature/bigfeature
298b93fe HEAD@{17}: merge origin/feature/bigfeature: Fast-forward 
94c8d1f0 HEAD@{18}: pull: Fast-forward
19553db9 HEAD@{19}: checkout: moving from feature/bigfeature to develop
```

so I know I could do a `git reset --keep develop@{N}` but again, it looks like I am losing lots of other merges into origin/develop that are not related to bigfeature. I guess the strategy would be to go all the way back in time and start doing cherry-picks. But is there another way?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? What should the end state look like?

Comment: If the idea is to reset `develop` to some past state, you can just reset the branch pointer to whatever SHA you want locally, and then force-push it.

Comment: In this case, I want develop to look exactly as it did before feature/bigfeature was merged into it.

Comment: @pkamb the problem with that is many merges were made into develop while bigfeature was developed and resetting to the past state would wipe out those changes

Comment: `bigfeature` was merged, and then other unrelated PRs into develop happened? Or was `bigfeature` the most recent PR? If it was the most recent PR, just reset dev. The only change lost would be the merge of that PR.

Comment: A fast-forward operation is not actually a merge at all. There is therefore nothing *to* revert. If you've made new commits since then, things get a little tricky, otherwise the reset is mostly the right thing to do *but* you have to remember that everyone else using the shared GitHub repository may have assumed that the fast-forward was correct and may now depend on it.

Comment: @torek in our small team we can control that. Is the strategy then to reset and force push? Given the reflog and console output I posted can you should me what the reset command should be?

Comment: Yes, reset and force-push. This actually has the two hashes of interest in it: `Updating 94c8d1f0..298b93fe`. The one on the left is the "before fast-forward" and the one on the right is the "after fast forward". I also see `94c8d1f0` on the `94c8d1f0 HEAD@{18}: pull: Fast-forward` line (note that above it, `@{17}`, is another fast-forward to reach the commit identified at that time by the name `origin/feature/bigfeature`).